# Iterate through a string to validate if it is a binary number

Tags: java, swing

The code compiles but the output is incorrect.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class binaryValidation
{

    public static void main( String [] args )
    {
        String inputUser = "";
        boolean binaryWord;
        inputUser = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null,
                                                            "Enter a Binary Word" );

        for ( int i = inputUser.length( ) - 1; i >= 0; i++ )
        {
            if ( inputUser.charAt( i ) == 0 ||  inputUser.charAt( i ) == 1 )



            JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null,
                        "The Binary Word is valid" );


            else            


            JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null,
                        "The Binary Word is not valid" );


        }
```

Comment: The output is correct for the code you have.

Comment: How's the output incorrect?  What's your input vs output?

Comment: You're confusing characters (`'0'`) with Unicode code points.

Comment: Yes, there is a major difference between the number `1` and the character value `'1'`.  The former has a value of (duh!) 1, while the latter has (in ASCII) a value of 49 decimal, 31 hex.  Presumably you want to check character values.

Answer (score 1):

This is business logic, don't intermingle Swing code here.  Extract your code to a method that is called `public boolean isBinary(String stringToCheck)`.

One thing you're doing wrong is `showInputDialog` on every iteration, instead of once on the result.

Another thing you're doing wrong is `== 0` and `== 1`.  `charAt` returns a `char`, not a number.  [You can see from this table](http://ascii.cl/), the numbers 0 and 1 are for NUL and SOH, not the characters 0 and 1.

You want to check that it equals `== '0'` and `== '1'` instead.

Comment: Another thing you're doing wrong is == 0 and == 1. charAt returns a char. You want to check that it equals '0' and '1' instead.